# How can I speed up the loading and inference of an LLM?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am currently using huggingfaces transformers library for a school project. The user prompts for an activity inside or outside, and I add their interests which I have stored in my database in order to get a tailored response. The problem is the prompting takes ~60 seconds to generate.

I am using a 4bit quantization of the llama2-7b model. I have a GTX 1080 8Gb vram with cuda 11.8.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

def run_chatbot(prompt):
    model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-GPTQ"

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path,
                                                device_map="auto",
                                                trust_remote_code=False,
                                                revision="gptq-4bit-64g-actorder_True")

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, use_fast=True)

    curr_prompt = prompt
    prompt_template=f'''[INST] <<SYS>>
    You are a helpful, respectful and honest assistant. Always answer as helpfully as possible, while being safe. Your answers should not include any harmful, unethical, racist, sexist, toxic, dangerous, or illegal content. Please ensure that your responses are socially unbiased and positive in nature. If a question does not make any sense, or is not factually coherent, explain why instead of answering something not correct. If you don't know the answer to a question, please don't share false information. 
    <</SYS>>
    {curr_prompt}[/INST]

    '''

    input_ids = tokenizer(prompt_template, return_tensors='pt').input_ids.cuda()
    output = model.generate(inputs=input_ids, temperature=0.7, do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, top_k=40, max_new_tokens=256)
    return tokenizer.decode(output[0])
```